# How to disable Android back button in ionic 3 pwa app

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3, progressive-web-apps

I am working on progressive web app with ionic 3 and angular 6 framework.
Every thing works fine but when I press my browser back button or mobile back button my application get closed.

I tried to search how to do this, I am able to disable browser back button with java script but on mobile app it's not working.

```
<script>
// window.onbeforeunload = function() { return "Your work will be lost."; 
};
  $ionicPlatform.registerBackButtonAction(function (event) {
       event.preventDefault();
      }, 100);

 </script>
```

I tried to register the back button event and lot's more but none of that is worked fine for me.

Can anyone have same issue then please tell me how to resolve this.

Thanks,
Dattatray

Answer (score 0):

You can use Ionic's Platform to override the physical back button on Android. 
Add it into app.component.ts file as such :

```
import { Platform } from 'ionic-angular';

constructor(public plt: Platform) {}


platform.registerBackButtonAction(() => {
  //Add your code here     
},100);
```

[Ionic Platform Service.](https://ionicframework.com/docs/v3/api/platform/Platform/#registerBackButtonAction)

Comment: I tried it but it's not working as expected. When I am trying to access the pwa on Android browser then it exit the app/site. also if i add the app to home screen using add to home screen option then if tried to push back button then it closes.

Comment: So you want it to go to the previous page instead ?

Comment: Forgive me if I am wrong, Actually I am using ionic 3 framework which does not have pagination.
So my app is SPA and if user click on device back button or browser back button then app gets closed and browser will go to previous page.

Comment: If it is single page then yes, that should be the behaviour.